# How do I fix Microsoft Access OLE Object fields that display "Microsoft Access can't open the file containing the OLE object" error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ole

### Background

I have an Access 2010 database where I am trying to export an OLE Object field to a corresponding Word document. I've successfully exported 900 records but 300 records will not with the following error information:

> - Err.Number: 2707
> - Err.HelpContext: 9360
> - Err.Description: Microsoft Office Access can't open the file containing the OLE object.

When I display any of the problem records in a Bound Object Frame then text from the Word document is displayed on screen. However when I double-click the frame to open the field in Word the alert box reads:

> Microsoft Access can't open the file containing the OLE object.
>
> - You may have specified an invalid file name or an invalid unit of data (such as a range of cells from a worksheet) within the file for
>     the OLE object.
> - The file you specified may not be available because it's locked by another user or you don't have permission to use it.
>
> Try one of the following:
>
> - Make sure the file is available and that you used the correct file name.
> - Check the OLE server's documentation for information about the syntax to use when specifiying an OLE object's data.

The error message suggests these records are using **linked** Word documents, this is not the case, they are all **embedded** Word documents.

### Question

1. How can I export these embedded Word documents?
2. Why can Access display their contents but I can't open or edit them?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sticky one. Because you've got most of them to work, you're clearly using a valid method of extraction.
MS Access and Office in general is typically extremely flaky in these kind of interoperability areas.

I think either (1) those records are corrupted, or (2) they have some 'feature' of word in them that is reacting badly to being OLE embedded.

Try

(a) going back to an earlier version or backup

(b) ensure the OLE object table is local, not linked, and get as close to the original setup (OS and Access Version) as possible when trying to retrieve data.